# Problem related to TFS workItem.Fields

Tags: tfs

i am getting following error,while accessing teamfoundation defect tracking application

"A field definition Symptom in the work item type definition file does not exist. Add a definition for this field or remove the reference to the field and try again."

can any body help?

Thanks
Suneetha.

Answer (score 0):

The work items types definition must have been modified : the "Symptom" type has probably been renamed or deleted.

This can be done using the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx#wit), if you are the admin on the TFS server.